# With ElasticSearch (C#/NEST) get all documents sorted by timestamp

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an elasticsearch database where I have a type and timestamp field defined as:

```
public Common.MediaType Type        { get; set; }
public DateTime Timestamp           { get; set; }
```

How can I do a query to return X entries, matching a specific type and sorted by timestamp?

If I do this:

```
        var Match = Index.Driver.Search<Metadata>(_ => _
            .Query(Q => Q.Term(P => P.Type, Type))
            .Size(NumberOfItems)
            .Sort(Q => Q.Descending(P => P.Timestamp)));
```

It will fail because it will return *NumberOfItems* records from the right type, and then sort them by timestamp, so it can very well miss the records with the newest timestamps.

What I want to is to make the timestamp part of the query so that I get *NumberOfItems* records sorted by *TimeStamp* that match the right type.

But I don't know how to write this...

Comment: _"It will fail because it will return NumberOfItems records from the right type, and then sort them by timestamp, so it can very well miss the records with the newest timestamps."_ - It's not clear what you mean here. That query will return you the latest _searchable_ `Metadata` that have a matching `Type`, ordered by `Timestamp` descending. Is that not what you want?

Comment: If I request 5 items, it will return 5 items matching type and then sort there 5 items by date. At least that's what the test I had indicates.
What I need is to make a query that will return the newest 5 items, out of the whole DB, that match the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so I understand correctly, the top 5 `Metadata` document types with the newest timestamps across all indices within a cluster?

If that's what you'd like then the following will work

```
var Type = "metadata-type";
var NumberOfItems = 5;

var searchResponse = client.Search<Metadata>(s => s
    .AllIndices()
    .Query(q => q
        .Term(f => f.Type, Type)
    )
    .Size(NumberOfItems)
    .Sort(sort => sort
        .Descending(f => f.Timestamp)
    )
);
```

`AllIndices()` will search for `Metadata` document types across all indices. If you want to search only within one specific index, or multiple specific indices, then you can replace `AllIndices()` with

```
.Index("index-1,index-2")
```

where the argument is a comma separated list of the index names you want to search across.

Something that you need to consider is that there is an interval between a document indexed into Elasticsearch and that document being available to search results. By default this interval is 1 second and that is the minimum amount of time that it can be set to.

**EDIT:**

From your comment:

> currently, If all records are of the right type and I want 5 items, it will take the first 5 and sort them; but maybe record 6 had a higher timestamp value but it will not be included in the result of the query matching the type.

How will Elasticsearch take the *first 5 items*? It will order the items first according to some value, and in this case, it will order according to timestamp descending as specified in the query, then return the top 5 documents. *It won't imply some arbitrary ordering of documents, take the first 5 and then order only these 5 by timestamp descending.*

Here's an example to demonstrate

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var defaultIndex = "default-index";
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
            .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<Metadata>(mm => mm.AutoMap())
        )
    );

    var metadata = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(i =>
        new Metadata
        {
            Id = i,
            Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-(i-1)),
            Type = i % 2 == 0? "metadata-type-2" : "metadata-type-1"
        });

    client.IndexMany(metadata);
    client.Refresh(defaultIndex);

    var Type = "metadata-type-1";
    var NumberOfItems = 5;

    var searchResponse = client.Search<Metadata>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .Term(f => f.Type, Type)
        )
        .Size(NumberOfItems)
        .Sort(sort => sort
            .Descending(f => f.Timestamp)
        )
    );
}

public class Metadata
{
    public int Id { get; set;}

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set;}

    [String(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string Type { get; set;}
}
```

For the search response, we get back

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 500,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "default-index",
      "_type" : "metadata",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : null,
      "_source" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "timestamp" : "2016-07-01T00:00:00Z",
        "type" : "metadata-type-1"
      },
      "sort" : [ 1467331200000 ]
    }, {
      "_index" : "default-index",
      "_type" : "metadata",
      "_id" : "3",
      "_score" : null,
      "_source" : {
        "id" : 3,
        "timestamp" : "2016-06-29T00:00:00Z",
        "type" : "metadata-type-1"
      },
      "sort" : [ 1467158400000 ]
    }, {
      "_index" : "default-index",
      "_type" : "metadata",
      "_id" : "5",
      "_score" : null,
      "_source" : {
        "id" : 5,
        "timestamp" : "2016-06-27T00:00:00Z",
        "type" : "metadata-type-1"
      },
      "sort" : [ 1466985600000 ]
    }, {
      "_index" : "default-index",
      "_type" : "metadata",
      "_id" : "7",
      "_score" : null,
      "_source" : {
        "id" : 7,
        "timestamp" : "2016-06-25T00:00:00Z",
        "type" : "metadata-type-1"
      },
      "sort" : [ 1466812800000 ]
    }, {
      "_index" : "default-index",
      "_type" : "metadata",
      "_id" : "9",
      "_score" : null,
      "_source" : {
        "id" : 9,
        "timestamp" : "2016-06-23T00:00:00Z",
        "type" : "metadata-type-1"
      },
      "sort" : [ 1466640000000 ]
    } ]
  }
}
```

We get back documents with ids `1`, `3`, `5`, `7`, and `9` in that order as these are the top 5 documents with the latest `Timestamp` value that match the query term `"metadata-type-1"`.

Comment: Currently all these solutions take NumberOfItems elements matching Type and sort the result by TimeStamp. What I am looking for is to find  NumberOfItems elements with the largest timestamp (the newest)  that are of the right Type. Essentially reversing the search into sorting the whole DB by Timestamp, and then scanning from the top of the list to find NumberOfItems matching the type.

Comment: currently, If all records are of the right type and I want 5 items, it will take the first 5 and sort them; but maybe record 6 had a higher timestamp value but it will not be included in the result of the query matching the type.

Comment: No, you're misunderstanding. I'll add an example

Comment: in pseudo code, I would need this: Data = DB.Sort(TimeStamp); foreach (var D in Data) { if (D is Type) { add to results} ; if (enough results) break; }

Comment: ok, now I realize that it works as it is intended; from the data I have, the results I am getting are not the expected ones. Possibly the problem is in another part of the query as I have another issue that may explain it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136227/elastic-search-query-c-nest-some-search-terms-ignored ; anyhow, thanks a lot for taking the time to put up the example!

Comment: @Thomas no worries, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use Take instead of Size.

```
var Match = Index.Driver.Search<Metadata>(_ => _
            .Query(Q => Q.Term(P => P.Type, Type))
            .Take(NumberOfItems)
            .Sort(Q => Q.Descending(P => P.Timestamp)));
```

This should sort first and then take first NumberOfItems documents.

Comment: `Take()` is just an alias for `Size()` :)